# Client-side or server-side context of Silverlight XAML

Tags: silverlight

Does the XAML file and its .cs code behind run on server-side or client-side? It would be nice if anyone can answer this in the context of Silverlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAML, its .cs code behind and other code attached to silverlight control project are compiled into .XAP file and are executed in browser, by silverlight plugin - so it's client-side.

Comment: Hey Hi PanJanek, so there is no doubt in saying that the Silverlight is a client-side technology.

Comment: @Malcolm: Yes. Silverlight is a standard example of client-side technology. More info here http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/what-is-silverlight/